# How do I set default options for traceur.compile and traceur.require?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, traceur

Using the official [traceur module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/traceur), is it possible to set the default options for `compile` and `require`?

For example, this code works:

```
var traceur = require('traceur');
console.log(
    traceur.compile('{ let x = 1; }', { experimental:true }).js
);
```

Now if I remove `traceur.compile`'s 2nd argument (the options object):

```
console.log(
    traceur.compile('{ let x = 1; }').js
);
```

Traceur will throw an error as the `blockBinding` option is not enabled. Is there any way to change the default options, in order to compile files without always passing an options object?

My main concern, apart from applying the DRY principle, is getting the `traceur.require` function to compile files with customized options -- as far as I can see, `traceur.require` and `traceur.require.makeDefault()` do not even take an `options` argument.

For instance, considering this code sample:

```
require('traceur').require('./index');
```

And this piece of code:

```
require('traceur').require.makeDefault();
require('./index');
```

Is there any way to compile the required file with the `experimental` option enabled?
Preferably by altering the default options, as I cannot see any other viable way.

Using Node 0.10.29 and Traceur 0.0.49.

---

Here's a full example of what I'd like to achieve.

bootstrap.js (entry point):

```
var traceur = require('traceur');
traceur.options.experimental = true;
traceur.require.makeDefault();
require('./index');
```

index.js:

```
import {x} from './lib';

// using a block binding in order to check
// whether this file was compiled with experimental features enabled
{
    let y = x;
    console.log(y);
}
```

lib.js:

```
export var x = (() => { 
    if (true) {
        // should be compiled with experimental features enabled too
        let x = 1;
        return x;
    }
})();
```

Expected console output: `1`

`traceur.options.experimental=true` serves as a setter which enables the experimental features in the `traceur.options` object, but unfortunately `traceur.options` does not seem to affect `traceur.compile` nor `traceur.require` as far as I can see.

---

The [Using Traceur with Node.js](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Using-Traceur-with-Node.js)  Wiki page does not mention anything about compiling options. The [Options for Compiling](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Options-for-Compiling) page does not mention the Traceur API in Node.js, in fact, I cannot find any documentation about the Traceur API in Node.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabrício Matté ;-) added support for giving the default options to makeDefault(), see
https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/blob/master/src/node/require.js#L58

A separate bug with the option `experimental` was fixed today, 16JUL14.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this question and posting an answer, I've been rather busy lately and almost forgot about this question. Welcome to Stack Overflow btw. `=]`